# Error: El componente activex no puede crear el objeto (vba excel 2013)

Tags: excel-2013, activex

Actualmente desarrollo en un complemento para excel en la empresa donde trabajo, este complemento debe realizar un " DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet " desde excel a una base de datos access, cuando ejecuto el complemento en excel 2016 funciona perfectamente, el problema radica cuando lo ejecuto en excel 2013.

Error: El componente Activex no puede crear el objeto

Se que debe se un tema de librerias pero la verdad he buscado y no encuentro cual es la correcta.

Alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: `DoCmd` es de Microsofts Access. ¿Has probado con dicha librería?